# Filter a list using tail recursion

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I am having a real tough time with tail recursion...

My current function filters out values less than 'n' from list 'l'

```
def filter(n: Int, l: List): List = l match {
   case Nil => Nil
   case hd :: tl => {
     if (hd < n) filter(n, tl)
     else hd :: filter(n, tl)
   }
}
```

When using large lists, this causes the stack to overflow.

Can someone please help me understand how to convert this to a tail recursive function?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: The essence of a tail recursive function is to return `terminal` value or make a call to itself. Brian has already posted a good example. In your snippet, you call a cons constructor which doesn't satisfy the condition of a tail recursivity. The reason why tail recursive function doesn't cause stack overflow is because it is converted to a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually done with a helper function that accumulates the results. `filterR` has an additional parameter `acc` that we add values that are greater than `n` to.

```
def filter(n: Int, l: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def filterR(n: Int, l: List[Int], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] =  l match {
    case Nil => acc
    case hd :: tl if(hd < n) => filterR(n, tl, acc)
    case hd :: tl            => filterR(n, tl, hd :: acc)
  }
  filterR(n, l, List[Int]())
}
```

With the suggestion from @jwvh:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def filter(n: Int, l: List[Int], acc: List[Int] = List[Int]()): List[Int] =  l match {
   case Nil => acc.reverse
   case hd :: tl if(hd < n) => filter(n, tl, acc)
   case hd :: tl            => filter(n, tl, hd :: acc)
}
```

Comment: Actually `filterR` isn't really necessary.  Just add `acc` as the 3rd argument to `filter`, but with a default value of `List.empty[Int]`, and the the client code need won't know the difference.

Comment: I don't know, is there a good reason to expose an implementation detail like that?

Comment: @jwvh that is one way to do it but it leaks an additional parameter to the public API. I believe the internals of the function should stay ... internal to the function. The auxiliary function is good solution, imo.

Comment: @Brian, correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like your first bit of code reverses the input list?

Comment: @naomik Ya, `::` in the third case statement inserts elements at the start of the accumulator and thus you get the filtered input in reverse order.

Answer (score 3):

@Brian's answer is nice but it reverses the input list. That's generally not the intended behaviour.

@jwvh's recommendation is pass the accumulator in a 3rd parameter to the function but that leaks private API to public API.

Either solution would necessitate reversing the accumulator before returning the answer – *effectively iterating thru your input list **twice***. That's an insane implementation, especially considering you're trying to implement this to facilitate large lists.

Consider this tail-recursive implementation which does not expose private API and does not require the accumulator to be reversed after filtering.

> **disclaimer:** this is the first scala procedure I have ever written. Feedback on any implementation style or detail is welcomed.

```
def filter(n: Int, xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def aux(k: List[Int] => List[Int], xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = xs match {
    case Nil => k(Nil)
    case x :: xs if (x < n) => aux(k, xs)
    case x :: xs            => aux((rest: List[Int]) => k(x :: rest), xs)
  }
  aux(identity, xs)
}

filter(5, List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)))
// => List(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: A clever implementation. A few things I noticed: 1) The OP wants to "filter **out** values less than n". In other words, `fiilterNot`. 2) `xs` in `aux()` shadows `xs` in `filter()`. That can lead to code confusion. 3) Parens `()` aren't needed for `case` pattern guards, but it does make the code look more consistent. Style issue. 4) I decided to test the efficiency of both answers. I created a `List` of 9000 random `Int`s between 0 and 10 and filtered for 5. I used [Rex Kerr's Thyme](https://github.com/Ichoran/thyme) utility and found that using `reverse` is the more efficient of the two.

Comment: @jwvh thanks for the exhaustive review. 1) fixed. 2) I see the potential for confusion but I'm intentionally shadowing `xs` so that `aux` cannot possibly touch the original input value, `xs` – it should only be able to work with data in its domain. 3) thanks, I did not know that. I kept the parens for readability in this case. 4) compelling find; for all sizes of `xs`, does filter+reverse perform better? If not, at what size `xs` does one implementation take the other over?

Comment: Prepend takes constant time while append and reverse are linear time in proportion to the length of the list. This is why you will typically see functions prepend and reverse the accumulator before returning instead of appending to the accumulator on each iteration.

Comment: @Brian, I understand why `::` is used to build linked lists. The OP's original post does not reverse the input, so I felt it was necessary to offer a solution that is tail-recursive and does not reverse the input.